Wordpress Plugin settings page not loading
I have a custom smm api plugin that i bought, and in the beginning it worked fine to open the settings page and add new APIs keys & urls. The problem is that now it simply doesnt load properly, giving a blank page (in the settings link) or a Error code 524 timeout.
thats the errors on console when the page goes blank after trying loading

i tried to free a lot of space on my hosting, going from 100% to 35% but it didn't work.
i also tested the same plugin on a wordpress localhost and i opened the settings page fine
the plugin is in three websites, i tried to dectivate it and exclude it, and install and activate again, but i could only open the settings page in one site(after 1 minute waiting for it to open)
-i tried opening the panel in different computers (also didn't work)
all of those 3 sites are in the same hosting plan

Just to know, im a wordpress beginner

Its probably a developer error. They probably used function names that arent unique, so its conflicting with other plugins.
Send them your error message and DON'T send them your admin login or access to your pc. They only ask for this, if they want to scam. Everything can be solved on their end.
I just use panelhelper for my smm panel, its in the wordpress store.
